# Linking static C++ archive file in Hello World app

Tags: c++, static-linking

I'm trying to link an archive file into my simple hello world app, to make sure I understand the process. However, I obviously don't, because the library isn't linking correctly.

Here is my simple app (hello.cc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "firebase/app.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my compilation command with linking:

```
gcc hello.cc -L /tmp -l app -o hello -lstdc++
```

I've moved my archive file (libapp.a) to /tmp.

My understanding is that `-L <dir>` adds directories to search for `lib*.a` files and `-l <name>` indicates the name of the archive files, in the form of `lib<name>.a`. I know it isn't linking the archive file, because I get this error:

```
hello.cc:3:26: fatal error: firebase/app.h: No such file or directory
 #include "firebase/app.h"
```

However, I also don't think the compilation command does what I think it does, because I renamed `libapp.a` to `libapp.a2` and the same error was returned, not something indicating that the archive file was missing.

Can somebody help me with a) the command to link the library file `/tmp/libapp.a` and b) explain what I'm doing wrong?

---

### EDIT

I forgot to include the headers, which caused the initial error I think. Now that I'm including the headers, with the following:

```
gcc hello.cc -L /tmp -l app -I /tmp/firebase/include -o hello -lstdc++
```

I get this new error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lapp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, I think I'm not using -L and -l correctly, but not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

---

### EDIT2

Fixed. Forgot I had renamed the lib file while trying to figure out the first issue. Once I named it back to `libapp.a` the app worked as expected.

Comment: Thats not a linker error though... It's looking for the header file, not the .a file.

Comment: the problem is with where the preprocessor searches for include files (headers). for your compiler set up e.g. the CPATH environment variable. or use `-I` option

Comment: The linker may not use any functions in your library since you are not calling any functions outside the C++ run-time library.  You are including a header but not calling any functions in the header.

Comment: Good point, Cheers... I forgot to link the headers. But linking the headers leads to this issue:  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lapp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Can you update the question?

Comment: The order of things on the command line probably matters - try moving the hello.cc after all the options that start with a minus sign.

Comment: It wasn't the order causing the second issue... it was the fact that I had renamed "/tmp/libapp.a" to "/tmp/libapp.a2" and forgot to name it back. Everything is working as expected now that I'm linking that headers. Thanks everyone.